# How do I avoid problems with the web design when updating bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This morning I updated Bootstrap CDN, from 4.0.0 alpha to beta.

This is how the web page (which is still under construction) looked before:

[Website, with Bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i9o1.jpg)

And this is how it looks now:

[With Bootstrap 4.0.0 beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU3Vr.jpg)

As you can see, the design has pretty much disintegrated. Why has it happened? Have I done something wrong when I updated Bootstrap or is it such big difference between the releases that I have to rewrite parts of the code. As you can see in the first image, I have some problems with a modal, but that is another matter.

Before I updated the CDN, I removed the framework from the project to avoid potential conflicts. The updated CDN:s is the only change I have made in the code.

This is how the head looked before the update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- BootStrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700i,900" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/frontend.js"></script>
<script src="js/backend.js"></script>
<title>Continuous integration for GIT repositories</title>
</head>
```

This is the code that is actual at this stage:
**CIApp.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- All images included in the project is free for commercial use -->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CDN -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700i,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/frontend.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backend.js"></script>
    <title>Continuous integration for GIT repositories</title>

     </head>

     <body>
     <!-- Kod för navigationsmeny-->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0" href="#">Continuous integration</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#Git">Add Git Repository</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#TestReport">View test results</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </nav>

     <div id="upperHalf">
         <div class="row"></div>
         <div class="col-6 .col-md-4">
             <h1 id="headLine">Enter your Git please</h1>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="lowerHalf">
         <div class="enterGitContainer">
             <div class="text-left">
                <form class="col-sm-10 form-group-lg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="projectNameContainer">
                            <label id="nameLabel" class="from-control-label" for="projectNameInput">Name your project</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="projectNameInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="gitRepoContainer">
                        <label id="gitLabel" class="from-control-label" for="repoInput">Enter you Git repository</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="repoInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="submitRepo" onclick="storeRepo()" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**layout.css**

```
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
border-radius: 0 !important;
border: 0;
}
#headLine{
font-family: "Abril Fatface";
font-size: 100px;
color: #ffffff;
}

#upperHalf {
background: url('../images/modernView.png') 50% 0 no-repeat;
max-width: 100%;
height: 50Vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 200px 0 260px 0;
background-size: cover;
}

#lowerHalf {
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
color: #333333;
height: 50Vh;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
display: flex;
float: none;
padding: 0 0 2rem;
}

#repoInput, #projectNameInput {
min-width: 600px;
max-width: 33%;
}
```

**frontend.js**

```
 $(window).on('load',function(){
     $('#modalForm').modal('show');  
 });
```

Comment: it's change between the previous bootstrap version and the new one. You will need to update your code

Comment: You didn't include bootstraps CSS in your second `head`.

Comment: @Vucko Thank you for your help!! That was the problem! Now the website looks like it did before!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead consider marking an answer as accepted or posting your own and marking that as accepted. This will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are using CDN online file. you have to download bootstrap files. then work on it.